# cmake. execute command after project files generation

Tags: cmake

I need to execute cmake instruction after all the files are generated. Here is the instruction I need to execute

```
file(RENAME ${DFA_FILE_PATH}_bu ${DFA_FILE_PATH})
```

I pasted this instruction in the end of `CMakeFiles.txt` file. However I found that at the moment of execution (of the instruction) not all files were generated.

Needed files are generated in subfolder so `add_custom_command` variant doesn't work for me. Also variant to make internal script which runs `cmake` and the do what I need is not suitable for me.
The question is there any way to run the instruction after all the files are generated? 
By "all files" I mean files, related to libpng (which is part of my project). In my cmake file pnglib files generated as following:

```
if(UNIX)
    set(DFA_FILE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libpng/scripts/pnglibconf.dfa)
    execute_process(COMMAND cp --preserve -T ${DFA_FILE_PATH} ${DFA_FILE_PATH}_bu)
    file(APPEND ${DFA_FILE_PATH} "option READ_eXIf off\noption WRITE_eXIf off")
endif()
set(PNG_SHARED FALSE CACHE BOOL "")
set(PNG_TESTS FALSE CACHE BOOL "")
set(SKIP_INSTALL_EXPORT TRUE)
set(PNG_INTEL_SSE on)
add_subdirectory(libpng)
set_target_properties(png_static PROPERTIES FOLDER "3rd party/png")
set_target_properties(genfiles PROPERTIES FOLDER "3rd party/png")
target_include_directories(png_static
    PUBLIC
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib
)
add_library(libpng ALIAS png_static)
if(UNIX)
    #restore original libpng/scripts/pnglibconf.dfa file
    file(RENAME ${DFA_FILE_PATH}_bu ${DFA_FILE_PATH})
endif()
```

Before generating of these files I do some changes in source code of pnglib, and after pnglib project files are generated I want to remove this changes.
However looks like original file is restored before the pnglib project files are generated

Comment: "not all files were generated." - Which files? How do you generate them (which command is used for generate them)? Please, be specific. Currently it is not clear what do you have and what do you want.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I updated initial post with code

Comment: `By "all files" I mean files, related to libpng (which is part of my project).` - Some libpng files are generated at **configuration** stage, so they are already created at the end of top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. But some libpng files are generated at **build** stage, using `add_custom_command`, `add_custom_target` and so on. *Build* stage comes after *configuration* one, when `CMakeLists.txt` are processed, so it is normal that these files are generated according to the restored content of `libpng/scripts/pnglibconf.dfa` file.